# Drools: Rules involving a Map from String to Object

Tags: java, drools, kie

I need help writing a Drools rule. I have two classes named Context and CreditReport.

Context is inserted as a fact into the knowledge session before the rules are fired.

I need to write a rule that prints 'Excellent' on the console when the Credit Score is more than 800.

Ideally, I'd insert CreditReport directly into the session, but unfortunately I do not have that option.

The rule that I've written doesn't look good as:

1. The **then** part has an **if statement**
2. I am type-casting Object to CreditReport

Thanks for your help!

// Context.java

```
public class Context {
    private Map<String, Object> data = Maps.newHashMap();

    public <T> T getData(final String key, final Class<T> clazz) {
        return clazz.cast(data.get(key));
    }

    public void putData(final String key, final Object value) {
        this.data.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

// CreditReport.java

```
public class CreditReport {
    private final String name;
    private final int creditScore;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getCreditScore() {
        return this.creditScore;
    }

}
```

// Main method

```
context.put("creditReport", new CreditReport("John", 810));
session.insert(Arrays.asList(context));
session.fireAllRules();
```

// Rule

```
rule "Excellent_Score"
when Context($creditReportObject : getData("creditReport"))
then
    final CreditReport creditReport = (CreditReport) $creditReportObject;
    if (creditReport.getCreditScore() >= 800) {
       System.out.println("Excellent");
    }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you insert a `List<Context>` containing a single Context object? The Java code should do

```
context.put("creditReport", new CreditReport("John", 810));
session.insert( context );
session.fireAllRules();
```

The rule can now be written as

```
rule "Excellent_Score"
when 
   Context( $creditReportObject : getData("creditReport") )
   CreditReport( creditScore > 800 ) from $creditReportObject 
then
   System.out.println("Excellent");
end
```

You could, of course, get and insert the CreditReport from Context. - I suspect it's more convoluted that what you've shown, but "I do not have that option" is a code smell anyway.

**Edit** A single rule for more than one reason for printing "excellent" could be written like the one below, although this isn't much better that two rules, considering that you can wrap the RHS into a method or DRL function.

```
rule "Excellent_Score_2"
when 
   Context( $creditReport : getData("creditReport"),
            $account: getData("account") )
   ( CreditReport( creditScore > 800 ) from $creditReport
     or
     Account( balance >= 5000 ) from $account )
then
   System.out.println("Excellent");
end
```

Comment: Thank you laune! You are right on all counts. One followup question. If the Context contains another object called Account. I'd like to write a Rule that would print 'Excellent' when either CreditReport.creditScore >= 800 OR Account.balance >= 5000? I know how to write a Rule with an AND relationship but not OR. I am trying to avoid using eval as well

Comment: Not much to be gained with a single rule - see my edit.

Comment: Got it. Thanks once again! :)